# Is the statement "the empty set is a subspace of every vector space" true of false?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

Is this statement true or false, and why?

> The empty set is a subspace of every vector space.

Comment: Do any of the vector space axioms fail?

Comment: i think the third but i am not quite sure

Comment: No $0$ vector, no vector space for you.

Comment: That depends on how the axioms are ordered...

Comment: By definition a subspace is not empty, because it must contain $0$.

Comment: Do write *exactly* what axiom fails as the numbering can be pretty different from place to place.

Comment: can you give an answer for this please?

Comment: i know but i didn't know how to post the question because the site wouldn't let me, it said that it was duplicate of the previous answer and i couldn't post it that

Comment: @MatematikaMatematika, please don't change the question to something totally new without at least saying that you've done so (and only if you asked the wrong question by accident).  In generally it's better to post a whole new question, especially when the first one has been answered.  Also, please include a summary of your attempts to answer it and a description of where you are stuck.  This will help people provide good answers at an appropriate level.

Comment: @MatematikaMatematika: I'm not sure I've encountered this error before. To be clear, you go to "ASK QUESTION" and it gives you an error message? Can you copy the text into the comments?

Comment: nevermind, thanks anyway

Answer (score 5):

Vector spaces can't be empty, because they have to contain additive identity and therefore at least $1$ element!

Answer (score 2):

The empty set isn't (vector spaces must contain $0$).

However, $\{0\}$ is indeed a subspace of every vector space.

Comment: For clarification, what "$0$" represents can be totally different from one context to the other.  For example in $\Bbb R^2$ one would have the "zero vector" is $(0,0)$, while instead in $\Bbb R^3$ it would be different: $(0,0,0)$. Indeed, $\Bbb R^2\cap \Bbb R^3=\emptyset$.  There is no set which is a subset of every vector space except the empty set but as mentioned that is not a sub*space* of any vector space.  On the other hand, given any vector space and letting $0$ represent the additive identity element of *that* space, we can indeed assert that $\{0\}$ is a subspace of that vector space.